# OpenProject email notifications not received

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openproject

I installed OpenProject using docker-compose. I configured SMTP settings and I received the test email correctly.

OpenProject is configured to send email notifications, but they are not being received.

I read that in the case of a manual installation, we need to activate background jobs. https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/manual/#activate-background-jobs

I wonder if I also should activate background jobs on a docker-compose-based installation. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same issue. In my case the problem was the "Worker" container didn't have a dns resolution and couldn't fetch the external domain.

What I did:

Check logs with

`docker-compose logs -f --tail 1000 | grep Mails::MailerJob`

Probably you'll be able to fetch this log:

`worker_1    | E, [2022-10-18T14:55:00.281584 #381] ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [Mails::MailerJob] [c80bfc5b-af2a-4533-ab7c-7acbb33714a9] Error performing Mails::MailerJob (Job ID: c80bfc5b-af2a-4533-ab7c-7acbb33714a9) from DelayedJob(mailers) in 20107.54ms: SocketError (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution):`

Go to the docker-compose.yml file and add the dns you want.

```
worker:
   dns:    
     - 8.8.8.8
     - "Your DNS IP"
```

Let me know if it worked for you as well.

Regards.